# Is it a good idea to authenticate the user by using an extra key instead of email/password? (API/JWT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, jwt

I’m building an API in Rails inside a project that’s using Devise to authenticate. I’m thinking about generating a unique key to every user. So, the user will have email/password/key. That way the user only will use the email and password to access the default web panel, but to access the API by a third-party application he will use the key to generate the JWT.

I would like that user doesn’t use the email/password to access the API.

My question is only if give the unique key to the user access the API is a good idea.

Usually, it works this way:
-> E-mail/Password to authenticate;
-> Receives a valid JWT;
-> Each subsequent request will include the JWT.

I'm thinking to do this way:
-> Extra token to authenticate;
-> Receives a valid JWT;
-> Each subsequent request will include the JWT.

- That extra token is not permanent, the user can generate a new one at any time.

Comment: You really want the user to authenticate with the identity provider using email and password (and ideally multi-factor ID) to obtain a JWT with a limited lifetime. Then when the user calls the API from their browser passing the JWT, the server can validate the signature on the JWT and use it to allow access.

Comment: No, I don't want the user to authenticate providing the email and password, I would like that user authenticates by using an extra key instead of he uses email and password.

Comment: What you seem to be talking about is a permanent token. And there are some pretty big security issues with issuing permanent tokens in the browser as its not the safest of environments.

Comment: He said that the token will be used for third-party applications, so I suppose not on the browser.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by third-party application?

Comment: It isn't exactly a permanent token, because the user changes it. It will be a token to be used instead of email/password. But the way to use the JWT will be the same. The user will authenticate by the extra token, and then he will receive the JWT normally.

Comment: Usually, it works this way:
-> E-mail/Password to authenticate;
-> Receives a valid JWT;
-> Each subsequent request will include the JWT.

I'm thinking to do this way:
-> Extra token to authenticate;
-> Receives a valid JWT;
-> Each subsequent request will include the JWT.

That way the user can avoid using the email/password. Accessing by API the user has limited access.

Comment: I mean the applications that will consume the data via API.

Comment: I added the new information to the topic.